# swift using map to convert from array to dictionary

Tags: swift

```
@Published private var rates = Dictionary<String, Double>()
```

This works

```
for e in res.rates {
 self.rates[e.currencySymbol] = e.rate
}
```

This is returning 0 elements

```
let _ = res.rates.reduce(into: self.rates){ $0[$1.currencySymbol] = $1.rate }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your ``res`` define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an empty dictionary because you haven't used the result of [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/reduce(into:_:)), you need to use the result of it and set it to your `rates` dictionary.

```
self.rates = res.rates.reduce(into: self.rates) { $0[$1.currencySymbol] = $1.rate }
```

You are thinking that when you pass `self.rates` reduce will use it to fill the result but it is just the initial result, so you can even set empty dictionary `[:]`.

```
self.rates = res.rates.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.currencySymbol] = $1.rate }
```